# check if data value is different

Tags: jquery, html, css

im trying to do something like below,which is when **manual put "red" in data-type,**
then it will **add class red** after cm-coupon ,and **if hasClass red, then will show the css for red.**
Same else if **data-type in div is "green"**, then it will **add class green after cm-coupon**, and **display the css for green**.

but i no idea to how call the data-type from html to script?
is it need using find(); or attr(); ?

```
<div class="cm-coupon data-type="red"></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
// document
    var coupon = $('div.cm-coupon');

    $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title"></div>');
    //if data-type = "red"
        $(this).addClass('red');
        $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">title-01</div>');
    // if data-type = "green"
        $(this).addClass('green');
        $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">title-02</div>');

    // Call each css with different class
    if (coupon.hasClass('red')) {
        $('.cm-coupon').css({"background" : "red", "padding": "20px 0"});
    } else if (coupon.hasClass('green')) {
        $('.cm-coupon').css({"background" : "green", "padding": "20px 0"});
    } else {
        return coupon;
    }
});//end
```

Comment: `data-type = "red"` is putting value `data-type == "red"` comparing value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before changing classes (add, remove, toggle, etc), make sure that these classes have their styles already declared in a stylesheet or `<style>` block. In the demo, `.red` and `.green` classes are declared in CSS so the `.css()` method called in OP code originally is unnecessary and has been removed.

The code is written to dynamically to handle any value from `data-type` and `data-title`.

When dealing with `data-*` attributes:

1. jQuery methods **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** and **[`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** methods can get/set values of `data-*`. Of these 2 methods, the former one, `.data()` is better suited to handle them.
2. **Syntax**:

   - Get value from...`$(selector).attr("data-red");`
   - Set value of...  `$(selector).attr("data-red", "red");`
   - Get value from...`$(selector).data("red");`
   - Set value of...  `$(selector).data("red", "red");`

**Details commented in demo**

**Click the boxes**

### Demo

```js
/* Added the typical click event...
*/
$('div.cm-coupon').on('click', function() {
  
  // Appending a div...
  $(this).append('<div class="cm-cp-title"></div>');

  // Get the data-type value
  var dType = $(this).data('type');
  
  // Get the data-title value
  var dTitle = $(this).data('title');
  
  // If data-type does exist...
  if (dType) {
    
    /* ...add the class dType and append another div
    || but this time add its dTitle to it
    */
    $(this).addClass(dType).append('<div class="cm-cp-title">' + dTitle + '</div>');

  } else {
  
    // ...otherwise end function
    return false;
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 600 16px/1.5 Consolas
}

.cm-coupon {
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  border: 3px double #444;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:64px;
  color: #fff
  }
.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px 0
}

.green {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="red" data-title='RED'></div>


<div class='cm-coupon' data-type='green' data-title='GRN'></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(element).data('type');` to get value of `data-type` from html

Comment: example like $("cm-coupon").data('red');
something like this?

Comment: No, if you want to get value of `$("cm-coupon")` just use `$("cm-coupon").data('type');` it will return `red`

Comment: btw its `$(".cm-coupon")` not `$("cm-coupon")`

Comment: And adding to the above comments you are missing a double quotes after the class name in the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="red"></div> //Double quotes was missing
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var coupon = $('div.cm-coupon');
  $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title"></div>');
  if ($(".cm-coupon").data('type') == "red")
  {
    $(this).addClass('red');
    $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">title-01</div>');
  }
  else if $(".cm-coupon").data('type') == "green")
  {
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $('.cm-coupon').append('<div class="cm-cp-title">title-02</div>');
  }
  // Call each css with different class
  if (coupon.hasClass('red')) 
  {
    $('.cm-coupon').css({"background" : "red", "padding": "20px 0"});
  } 
  else if (coupon.hasClass('green')) 
  {
    $('.cm-coupon').css({"background" : "green", "padding": "20px 0"});
  } 
  else 
  {
    return coupon;
  }
});//end
```

- You were missing a double quotes after the class name in html.
- Condition for if statement was not proper.

Comment: but i use $(this).addClass("red"), it cant work ,got problem for my addClass there?

Comment: By $(this) which element are you targeting?

Comment: $(".cm-coupon"), target for this ya

Comment: thank you,i found i wrong to put $(this) , problem solved,thanks again ~！

Comment: yes you cannot access the element by $(this) inside an if. i didn't see that first. Glad you have solved it.

Comment: Btw,i found a problem, if <div class="cm-coupon" data-type="red"></div> have duplicate in html, means i got another cm-coupon div which data-type is green, but in the end the second cm-coupon is still show the content of data-type="red" although i change the data-type to green,how come? is it need to remove class too?

Comment: Try to give id's for every div and access them with those id's instead of class, if you want them to behave differently. And to apply common things you can use class.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get `data-type` value like below.

```
var data_type = $('.cm-coupon').attr('data-type');
```

it's return data-type value.

**demo**

```js
var data_type = $('.cm-coupon').attr('data-type');
console.log(data_type);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="red"></div>
```